# submitting a form with onSubmit form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit

This is my code to validate and submit a form. It works well on the validation part but it doesn't get submitted...!
Do you know what's wrong with it?

At first I created a form for registration, then I coded a function named check() to validate my form. It does validate my form but it doesn't return true when all the info is correct...!

.
.
.

function check(){

```
var error=0;

var fname=$("input[name=fname]").val();

var lname=$("input[name=lname]").val();

var email=$("input[name=email]").val();

var pwd=$("input[name=pwd]").val();

var confirmpwd=$("input[name=confirmpwd]").val();

var tel=$("input[name=tel]").val();

var mobile=$("input[name=mobile]").val();

var postalcode=$("input[name=postalcode]").val();

var address=$("textarea[name=address]").val();

var state=$("#statediv option:selected").val();

var city=$("#citydiv option:selected").val();

var captcha=$("input[name=captcha]").val();

if( fname=='' ){ error=1; $("#fnameErr").html('لطفا نام خود را وارد کنید.'); 
$("input[name=fname]").addClass('red');  }
else{ $("#fnameErr").hide(); $("input[name=fname]").removeClass('red'); }

if( lname=='' ){ error=1; $("#lnameErr").html('لطفا نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید.'); 
$("input[name=lname]").addClass('red');  }
else{ $("#lnameErr").hide(); $("input[name=lname]").removeClass('red'); }

var regexp=/^[a-z0-9_\.-]+@{1}[a-z0-9_\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,5}$/i;

if(regexp.test(email)==false){error=1; $("#emailErr").html('لطفا ایمیل خود را به درستی وارد کنید.'); 
$("input[name=email]").addClass('red');  }
else{ $("#emailErr").hide(); $("input[name=email]").removeClass('red'); }

regexp=/.{5,}/i;

if(regexp.test(pwd)==false){error=1; $("#pwdErr").html('لطفا رمز عبور خود را به درستی وارد کنید.'); 
$("input[name=pwd]").addClass('red');  }

else{if(pwd!=confirmpwd){error=1; $("#confirmpwdErr").html('تکرار رمز عبور نادرست است.'); 
$("input[name=confirmpwd]").addClass('red'); }

else{$("#confirmpwdErr").hide(); $("input[name=confirmpwd]").removeClass('red');
$("#pwdErr").hide(); $("input[name=pwd]").removeClass('red');}

}


regexp=/^0{1}[0-9]{10,12}$/i;

if(regexp.test(tel)==false){error=1; $("#telErr").html('لطفا شماره ثابت خود را به درستی وارد کنید.'); 
$("input[name=tel]").addClass('red');  }
else{ $("#telErr").hide(); $("input[name=tel]").removeClass('red'); }

regexp=/^0{1}9{1}[0-9]{9}$/i;

if(regexp.test(mobile)==false){error=1; $("#mobErr").html('لطفا شماره همراه خود را به درستی وارد کنید.'); 
$("input[name=mobile]").addClass('red');  }
else{ $("#mobErr").hide(); $("input[name=mobile]").removeClass('red'); }

regexp=/^[0-9]{10}$/i;

if(regexp.test(postalcode)==false){error=1; $("#postalcodeErr").html('لطفا کد پستی خود را به درستی وارد کنید.'); 
$("input[name=postalcode]").addClass('red');  }
else{ $("#postalcodeErr").hide(); $("input[name=postalcode]").removeClass('red'); }


if( address=='' ){ error=1; $("#addressErr").html('لطفا آدرس خود را وارد کنید.'); 
$("textarea[name=address]").addClass('red');  }
else{ $("#addressErr").hide(); $("textarea[name=address]").removeClass('red'); }

if(state==0){error=1; $("#stateErr").html('لطفا استان خود را وارد کنید.'); 
$("#statediv").addClass('red');}
else{ $("#stateErr").hide(); $("#statediv").removeClass('red'); }

if(city==0){error=1; $("#cityErr").html('لطفا شهر خود را وارد کنید.'); 
$("#citydiv").addClass('red');}
else{ $("#cityErr").hide(); $("#citydiv").removeClass('red'); }

if(error==0){

    $.ajax({

        url:'checkcaptcha.php',
        type:'post',
        async:false,
        data:{captcha:captcha}          

        })

    .done(function(msg){

        if(msg==1){ error=1; $("#captchaErr").html('لطفا عبارت درست را وارد کنید.'); 
        $("input[name=captcha]").addClass('red'); }
        else{ $("#captchaErr").hide(); $("input[name=captcha]").removeClass('red'); }


        })

}

if(error==0){
$.ajax({

        url:'checkmobile.php',
        type:'post',

        data:{mobile:mobile}            

        })

    .done(function(msg){

        if(msg==1){ error=1; alert('این شماره موبایل قبلا ثبت شده است!'); 
        $("input[name=mobile]").addClass('red'); }
        else{  $("input[name=mobile]").removeClass('red'); }


        })

}


if(error==0){
$.ajax({

        url:'checkemail.php',
        type:'post',

        data:{email:email}          

        })

    .done(function(msg){

        if(msg==1){ error=1; alert('این ایمیل قبلا ثبت شده است!'); 
        $("input[name=email]").addClass('red');  }
        else{ $("input[name=email]").removeClass('red'); }


    })

}



if(error=1){ return false; }

return true;

}
```

Comment: "if(error=1){ return false; }" at the end of the code before "return true" should be "if(error==1){ return false; }"

Comment: Thx man, I was careless while coding...!

Comment: happens to most of us, take care..:)